# How replace Space ONLY before and after Character not before and after number

Tags: javascript

all i tryed and found, will remove all spaces. But thats not what i want

my string is

```
 var str = "24 july 2014 12 5";
```

i want

```
"24july2014 12 5"
```

i found this code example

```
var str = "Paul m'a dit « Bonjour ! »";
str = str.replace(/\s([!:\?…;»])/g, function (el1, el2) {
return '&nbsp;' + el2;
}).replace(/(«)\s/g, function (el1, el2) {
return el2 + '&nbsp;';
});
console.log(str);
```

but its not changeable to my problem. maybe i`am too much noob?

Comment: the first and second space is also before and after a number.

Comment: "12 july 2014 12 5".replace(/\s+([a-z])|([a-z])\s+/ig,'$1')

Comment: mmmh but than i become "24jul2014 12 5" so the "y" is missing

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```js
var str = "24 july 2014 12 5";

str = str.replace(/ (?=[a-z])/g,  "").replace(/([a-z]) /g,  "$1");
console.log(str);
```

JS doesn't support lookbehinds, so one workaround is to use capturing groups and echo. The other replace is supported by a lookahead.

---

OP, based on your comment, it seems like you also wish to decode URL params. This is the right way to do it:

```js
string = "alabama%20justin";
console.log(decodeURIComponent(string));
```

Comment: This is a very clean solution.

Comment: New Problem->Can you tell me how i can replace in a string like "alabama%20justin" the "%20". so i want "alabama justin"
oh i got it. solution->str.replace(/%\d{2}/g," ")

Comment: @user2826395: You should _not_ use regex for that. Check my edit.

Comment: @user2826395: In future, unrelated questions always must be asked in a new thread. If this answer helped you, do consider accepting it please...

Comment: @user2826395 Also, please don't use regex to substitute that value. It's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a more fancy way but simple check to see if it is a space followed by alpha or an alpha followed by a space

```
"12 july 2014 12 5".replace(/\s+([a-z])|([a-z])\s+/ig,'$1$2')
```

or

```
"12 july 2014 12 5".replace(/\s+([\D])|([\D])\s+/ig,'$1$2')
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much

Comment: New Problem->Can you tell me how i can replace in a string like "alabama%20justin" the "%20". so i want "alabama justin"
oh i got it. solution->str.replace(/%\d{2}/g," ")

Comment: Seems like a new question to me.... lol... but seems like it is a simple replace(/%20/g,' ')